# Create MySQL event and run first day of the year

Tags: mysql, events

I had a problem on MySQL event. I want this event run every first day of the year. Currently my event will run on every month. Here is my event script.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT create_ledger
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
STARTS '2016-05-20 11:33:01'
 DO 
  BEGIN
    insert into ledger SET ledger_year= YEAR(CURDATE());
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

hope someone can help. TQVM

Comment: This almost seems too obvious - although really this kind of problem is often indicative of poor design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have MySQL rights to create events, the basic syntax is:

```
CREATE EVENT `event_name` 
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE] 
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
DO BEGIN
    -- event body
END;
```

In your case just use:

```
CREATE EVENT create_ledger
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR
    ...
```

You may set STARTS & ENDS :

```
STARTS '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
ENDS '2031-01-01 00:00:00'
```